# Get counts and results from different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

We are trying to get results from Table1, Table 2 and get the count of column for each result id in Table 3,4.

Below is our tables:

```
Table1 - Posts
----------------------------------
id  |  date   | Tilte  | AuthorID|
----------------------------------
321 | 2016-01 | test1  |   23234 | 
423 | 2016-01 | test2  |   56752 | 
324 | 2016-01 | test3  |   32433 | 
546 | 2015-12 | test4  |   45354 |

Table2 - eg. Author Details (Get author's Name based on Table1.AuthorID)
---------------
id    |  Name |
------|-------|
23234 | test1 |
56752 | test2 |
32433 | test3 | 
45354 | test4 | 

Table3 - eg. likes (COUNT if logged in user likes this post based on post ID (Table1.id and userID = loggedinUserid))
-----------------------------
id    | post_id |  userID   |
------| ------- |-----------|
32131 | 321     |     23234 |
42324 | 423     |.    56752 |
32423 | 324     |     32433 | 
54623 | 546     |     45354 | 

Table4 - eg. favorites (COUNT if user favorited this post based on post ID (Table1.id and userID = loggedinUserid))
--------------------------
id    | post_id | userID |
------| --------|--------|
32133 | 321     | 23234  |
42334 | 423     | 56752  |
32423 | 324     | 32433  | 
54687 | 546     | 45354  |
```

I have tried with UNION and JOIN but I get only results that exist in favorites/likes tables. I need 6 results (LIMIT 6) from posts Table1 and check if user has liked/favorited each.

Expected JSON Output:

```
{
  posts: [{
    "postID": 321,
    "postDate": "20/10/2020",
    "postTitle": "Test",
    "author": "Jack",
    "userLiked": "yes",
    "userFavorited": "no",
   },
   .....
  ]
}
```

Comment: show us the expected output and why 6? Do you want list of posts with their auther and likes and favorites count?

Comment: @JitendraYadav It's a list of posts with these details

Comment: @JitendraYadav I edited my question with the expected output

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` for this

Comment: @Slava Rozhnev can you create the sql based on these tables? I have used left join but it returns only results that exist in table favourites or likes, not all posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider you logged in `user_id = 123`.

- Use it in the `ON` clause to join only favorites and likes for current logged in user only.
- Make sure you do `LEFT JOIN` on both `likes` and `favorites` table, as if current logged in user is not liked or favorited then posts still should be part of our resultset.

```
SELECT
    p.id AS postID,
    p.`date` AS postDate,
    p.title AS postTitle,
    a.author AS author,
    IF(COUNT(DISTINCT l.id) > 0, 'yes', 'no') AS userLiked,
    IF(COUNT(DISTINCT f.id) > 0, 'yes', 'no') AS userFavorited
FROM Posts p
INNER JOIN `Authors` a ON p.AuthorID = a.id
LEFT JOIN likes l ON p.id = l.post_id AND l.userID = 123
LEFT JOIN favorites f ON p.id = f.post_id AND f.userID = 123
GROUP BY p.id, p.`date`, p.`title`, a.author
```

To limit records, use `LIMIT` clause and to filter out `posts` using `WHERE` clause.